Will a zigzag trunk with a knot in it bring any long term strength concerns?
I've had decent luck buying the discounted tree's from a site online. Most annoying thing is some are grown in mass groups so you end up with a 4' tall pencil like this bendy guy.
Anyways, This is the trunk of my 4' sawtooth oak. Would all the bends and knots and some missing bark bring many long term concerns? I'm okay with some fun characteristics, just don't want to waste time and energy on something if it seems obvious that it'll break in 5 years.... Thanks


I'm not an expert, but I would be most worried about the missing bark so close to the base.

I got a year warranty on this bad boy, so I'm hoping any bark issues would show by then but not sure.. Also just hoping all the zigs and zags in the trunk aren't obvious "weak" points in the far future when the tree is big and heavy..

I don't know they would necessarily show - but the tree will likely be a lot less vigorous then it should be. I would give it back/swap it out.

The company got back with me and basically said some warm and fuzzy generic statement about how it's probably still shaking off it's stress from being shipped and will be absolutely great in time.. I guess I'll re-evaluate later next year since it's warranty goes till next fall.... Thanks all

They are BS'ing you. Bark does not grow back.  I bet you they will turn around and say it is OK if you keep it - it won't die - it just won't thrive.
